# git diff of an untracked file against branch that has the same file showing diff

Tags: git

I have 2 files, file1 and file2.
file1 is in master.
branch1 is a branch created off master.
file2 is in branch1 only.

When I do this, I see a diff.

```
$ git checkout branch1
Switched to branch 'branch1'

$ cat file2
branch1 file

$ cp file2 file2_bak

$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

$ mv file2_bak file2

$ git diff branch1
diff --git a/file2 b/file2
deleted file mode 100644
index 6fbd376..0000000
--- a/file2
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-branch1 file
```

Why is it showing a diff when file2 exists in both branch1 and local?  Is there a way to prevent this diff from showing up?

Comment: If it's not critical, just use regular diff: `diff file1 file2`

Comment: @Blacksilver file1 and file2 are not the same.  file2 on branch1 is now the same as local but as an untracked file in local and local is pointed to master.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the question: What is a "/dev/null diff"?

Comment: @Blacksilver my last command is "git diff branch1".  It shows a difference on file2.  But there shouldn't be a difference as file2 is same on branch1 and local.  Is there a way to suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

Your command `git diff branch1` compares `branch1` with your current working tree. But git diffs only stuff it tracks -- for git there is no `file2` in `master`, only in `branch1`. The diff is the "change" required to get FROM the state in `branch1` TO the state in `master` -- which means the existing `file2` must be deleted. If you would do `git diff HEAD branch1` instead then the diff is from `master`  to `branch1` and the file would added. But all that only holds for tracked files.

There is one thing you can simplify a little bit: You don't need to switch branches to get `file2`. In `master` you can do

```
git cat-file blob branch1:file2 > file2
```

Comment: Thanks.  So I guess there's no way to diff this file?  Basically, what I'm trying to do is I have a file from somewhere else and I want to put this into my local and check if it's the same as the one on branch1, but I don't want to checkout branch1.